# How to notify about state change if it is an instance of a class in jetpack compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

I've got code like this:

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            TestsTheme {
                var myvalue = remember{ mutableStateOf(4)}
                Row() {
                    CustomText(myvalue = myvalue)
                    CustomButton(myvalue = myvalue)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun CustomButton(myvalue: MutableState<Int>) {
    Button(onClick = {myvalue.value++}) {

    }
}

@Composable
fun CustomText(myvalue: MutableState<Int>) {
    Text("${myvalue.value}")
}
```

When I click CustomButton, CustomText recomposes and changes it's value (and it is ok), but if I replace myvalue with an object of some class it does'nt work

How do I make the CustomText recompose if myvalue is now an instance of TestClass and it changes in the code below?

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            TestsTheme {
                var myvalue = remember{ mutableStateOf(TestClass(4))}
                Row() {
                    CustomText(myvalue = myvalue)
                    CustomButton(myvalue = myvalue)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun CustomButton(myvalue: MutableState<TestClass>) {
    Button(onClick = {myvalue.value.a++}) {

    }
}

@Composable
fun CustomText(myvalue: MutableState<TestClass>) {
    Text("${myvalue.value.a}")
}

data class TestClass(var a: Int) {

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Compose can only understand that it should recompose if you set the value of a `State` object. In your example `myvalue.value++` is really just short for `myvalue.value = myvalue.value.inc()`, so what triggers the recomposition is calling the `state.value` setter. 
If you just mutate a property of the object held by a state, you are not calling the setter and no recomposition happens.

So you have 2 options to solve this:

1. Make `TestClass` immutable and update the `State` with a new object

```
data class TestClass(val a: Int) { // << changed var to val

}

@Composable
fun CustomButton(myvalue: MutableState<TestClass>) {
    Button(onClick = {
        val current = myvalue.value
        myvalue.value = current.copy(a = current.a + 1)
    }) {

    }
}
```

This is not really nice to read but doesn't require `TestClass` to contain any compose-specific code.

2. Make `TestClass` a state holder

```
class TestClass(a: Int) { 
    var a by mutableStateOf(a)
}


@Composable
fun Parent(){
    val myvalue = remember{ TestClass(4) } // no mutableStateOf, state is managed inside the object
    CustomButton(myvalue = myvalue)
}
@Composable
fun CustomButton(myvalue: TestClass) {
    Button(onClick = { myvalue.a++ }) {

    }
}
```